# mysql cluster group by performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance, cluster-computing, mysql-cluster

I am working on database performance optimization issue, and I did a simple test on mysql cluster, the question is why a single group by statement in 30M records will take 1m20s so long.

**environment:**

linux x64 centos

mysql cluster 7.4.8

**cluster:**

1 master node 32GB memory, 40 core cpu

3 data nodes 32GB memory, 40 core cpu(each node)

3 sql nodes 32GB memory, 40 core cpu(each node)

**test case:**

test in "test" database
[image]

30,000,000 recods in test tables

**test sql：**

`select count(*), sum(impress), sum(click) from test1 group by entitykey order by null;`

2m20s with entitykey column indexed.
1m20s without entitykey column  indexed.

**this test result confuses me, why it's so painful slow**

**comparison:**

MS SQL SERVER: lenovo notepad, 8GB memory, disk storage, i5 8 core cpu, **finished in 10s!**

I am wondering, if I missed some sql node configuration or something else?

Comment: `2m20s with Indexed, but only 1m20s without Index`...?!!

Comment: In all three timings, did you determine whether the data was cached in RAM or came from disk?  Run each query twice.

Comment: mysql test data cached into memory, i have assigned 10GB data memory and 5GB index memory on data node. SQL SERVER is a disk storage.

Comment: @TheCoder yes, it's true!!! i did test three times!!!